# Create an alias for a complex type without subclassing?

Tags: c#, alias

I have a complex type in my program that results in very long line lengths. Here it is:

```
List<FruitCallback<Fruit>>
```

Here's an example of where the line of code is simply too long and confusing:

```
private static Dictionary<Type, List<FruitCallback<Fruit>>> callbacks = new Dictionary<Type, List<FruitCallback<Fruit>>>();
```

I can create an alias for it by subclassing it like so:

```
class FruitCallbacks : List<SomeClass.FruitCallback<Fruit>> { }
```

But I could of sworn I remember reading somewhere about a way to alias something like this such that an empty class would not be necessary.

Comment: You can at least use the `var` keyword on the left side of the assignment to save typing and enhance readability.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of the var keyword but I have to repeat this several other places where the var keyword cannot be used.

Comment: DarthVader's answer is what you need

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add a *fully qualified* `using` statement to your class file (in the using directives section) to alias the class. It's a bit verbose.

```
using MyType = System.Collections.Generic.List<YourNamespace.FruitCallback<YourNamespace.Fruit>>;
```

And then you can `MyType` in place of `List<FruitCallback<Fruit>>` in your code.

Full working example.

```
// aliased outside the namespace
using MyList = System.Collections.Generic.List<Bar.FruitCallBack<Bar.Fruit>>;

namespace Bar
{
    // alternately, can be aliased inside the namespace 
    // using MyList = System.Collections.Generic.List<FruitCallBack<Fruit>>;        

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var myList = new MyList();
        }
    }

    public class FruitCallBack<T> { }
    public class Fruit { }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can do this:

```
using Foo =  List<FruitCallback<Fruit>>;
```

Then you can use Foo everywhere you need to use `List<FruitCallback<Fruit>>`
Example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Foo =  List<FruitCallback<Fruit>>;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
      Foo f = new Foo();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to mention, you have to add this line next to the using directives (you never know if someone was going to use it within a class)

Comment: You also need to fully qualify the type.  See Anthony's answer.

Comment: Hah, I tried something exactly like this but it wouldn't compile because I was outside of a namespace. I tried it again within a class and it didn't work so I asked this question. Apparently it has to be within a namespace but not within a class.

Comment: @DarthVader: I believe your code edit is wrong. That is what I originally attempted as well. Apparently it has to be within a namespace. In your code sample it is out in the open. (Not sure if the namespace is implied there but I think it would be best to be explicit for future readers)

Comment: @RyanPeschel It doesn't need to be in a namespace. If it isn't in a namespace, you just need to fully qualify it. Like: `using Foo = System.Collections.Generic.List<string>;`

Comment: @DarthVader Adding `System.Collections.Generic` will not work. You need to fully qualify it. See Anthony's answer.

Comment: @IlianPinzon: Yeah I just realized that as you posted. In that case the code sample is still wrong. Either place it within a namespace of fully-qualify the type names.

Comment: I agree on that, in my example it wasnt fullu qualified name. hence i added the full namespace ahead of it in case, it s used somewhere else.

Comment: @RyanPeschel: Then accept the correct answer which is Anthony's.

Comment: @DarthVader: Yes but adding the namespace before it doesn't change anything. You still need to fully qualify it if it is not within a namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you were thinking of aliasing a type through a using statement?

```
using MyType = MyCompany.MyProject.DataAccess.Interfaces.MyType;
```