# Name a complex type

Tags: c#, class, type-declaration

I am looking for a way to name a complex type with a simple name.
Example

instead of

```
Dictionary<string,List<Dictionary<string,string>>> myvar = ...
```

just do some magic and I sould be defining my myvar as

```
MyNewType myvar = new MyNewType()
myvar = ....
```

I can always do

```
class MyNewType{
   public  Dictionary<string,List<Dictionary<string,string>>> myvar ;
}
```

but than I need to type

```
MyNewType myType = new myNewVar();
myNewVar.myvar = ....
```

which requires a dummy myNewVar for each referance to myvar

Regards

Comment: Don´t try to tweek lists of dictionaries into something that **seems** smart, but just hides complexity. Instead of messing around with such data-structures, give it a meaningful name and **extract a class-structure**. Define the types of entitities that you want to consider and create the relations between those. This seems a bit more work at the beginning, but I bet it´ll save you from headaches as soon as your world gets a bit more complex.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7829530/create-an-alias-for-a-complex-type-without-subclassing) seems similar.

Comment: If this is a local variable, use `var`: Instead of `Dictionary<string,List<Dictionary<string,string>>> myvar = ...` do this: `var myVar = new Dictionary<string,List<Dictionary<string,string>>>()`

Comment: Maybe you could give a bit more context. What do you actually want to **achieve**? What is your use-case here? Why do you have such a strange data-structure?

Comment: You *could* put `using MyNewType = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>>>;` at the top of every code file where you want to shorten the type name, so then you could just use `var x = new MyNewType();` (but see the other comments here!)

Comment: Thanks for the answers. For the complex type, I made it up. The point was that there is a complex type that i did not want to type every time.

Answer (score 2):

The best tip I can give you - though it won´t answer your question **being posted** - is: don´t do this. Don´t try to tweek a complex data-structure into something that simple as a `Dictionary`. Usually when you design such concepts, you have some kind of datatable in your mind. The table in itself has no meaning and thus you think: my table has a number of attributes. So I have a dictionary whose keys are strings - the names of those attributes. And those attributes can occur a number of times, so it itself is a list of something. This concept grows and grows and you end up in a huge system of lists and maps that are impossible to maintain as no-one exactly knows which part of your entitiy-model you actually refer to when you write `myType.MyVar["Attribute"][1]["AnotherAttribute"]`. It seems smart at the beginning, but as your requirements change - and they **will** - it´ll become a maintainance-nightmare. Imagine you get a new attribute which is of type number actually. But shit, your dictionary just consists of strings and other lists, no space for a number at all. So you tweek your number as string, leading to much cumbersome conversions, e.g. `ToString` and back to `int`.

So what else? I described an entitiy-model above. You have a set of tables in mind, where every tables has a set of attributes. So let´s be *specific*: **what attributes**? Which types do they have? And how can I find a common name for an entity within that table? As soon as you answer these questions, you have an easy to understand and easy to extend class-structure. E.g. a `Car` does have *Wheel`s, usually four. So you have a`List`here. Maybe it also has some creator, e.g`BMW`or`Mercedes`, those are pretty sure string-attributes. And it may have a creation-date, which is a`Date`. Thus your class looks like this:

```
class Car
{
    public string Creator { get; set; }
    publi Date CreationDate { get; set; }
    public List<Wheel> Wheels { get; set; }
}
```

A `wheel` on the other hand can have a `Size`. which probably is some number-format. So instead of a dictionary like this:

```
myCar["Wheels"][2]["Size"] // hmmm, what type is Size? a double? an int?
```

you know have this far easier approach:

```
myCar.Wheels[2].Size // nice, we have a double at compile-time.
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if you want to name a concept, you should make it a `class` (or `struct`, in some cases). Especially for such seemingly complex structures like nested dictionaries. Most of the time, there is additional logic inherent to such structures that would be best modelled as its own type.

If you're absolutely convinced that you need a new "type", you can always define an alias for the file:

```
using MyType = Dictionary<string,List<Dictionary<string,string>>>;
```

This goes along with all other `using`s at the top of each file where you want to use this alias. Note that from the "outside", this alias will not be known. So a method like

```
public MyType DoStuff(){ ... }
```

will still be shown as

```
public Dictionary<string,List<Dictionary<string,string>>> DoStuff()
```

for all consuming code.